# Using awk Printf to print a full number

Tags: awk, scripting, printf

I'm using FSL (a neuroimaging programme) and I have a for loop to analyse all my participants.
The line in question is :

```
fslstats <FILENAME> -M -V | awk '{print $1 * $3 }'
```

How do I get the awk function to print the whole number, rather than something like 9.37157e+07

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something specific, you'll have to supply a format, e.g.,

```
fslstats <FILENAME> -M -V | awk '{printf "%d\n", $1 * $3 }'
```

or

```
fslstats <FILENAME> -M -V | awk '{printf "%f\n", $1 * $3 }'
```

Comment: This will print in non-floating _format_, but generally not more than 16 significant _digits_ if that's what OP meant by 'full number'. Unless you have recent GNU awk and use `-M/--bignum`.

Comment: OP didn't say **that**.  The example given has no more than ***8*** digits: `9.37157e+07`.

Comment: The format for print is set by OFMT, and default is "%.6g", which switches to scientific notation if the result is more than a few digits. printf "%f" defaults to "%.6f", which rounds to 6 decimal digits. The format "%.15f" will give you a fixed.format with 15 digits after the point, and %.15g will defer the switch to scientific notation.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Not necessarily 8 digits: `echo 9.3715688345626 | awk '{ print 1e7 * $1 }'` yields `9.37157e+07`.